# Is componentDidMount causing html.script to disappear?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am having issues mounting an external script into a component of my React/Gatsby App. The script below is called into a component that is used in two places throughout app.

First being `pages/index.js` and loads fine with zero issue, yet when called to use within a `gatsby` created page (`exports.createPages = ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => {`) from a template the script will load, show content and then go.

Here is the code for the script being mounted into the component -

```
componentDidMount () {
    const tripadvisor = document.createElement("script");
    tripadvisorLeft.src = "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=789&locationId=10467767&lang=en_NZ&rating=true&nreviews=0&writereviewlink=true&popIdx=true&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2";
    tripadvisorLeft.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(tripadvisor);
}
```

I am not getting any errors from the console.

NOTE: Incase of relation to the error? I also have this code using `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` in the `/layout/index.js` file that handles a `body` `class` for `navigation` elements.

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({loading: ''});
  }, 100);
  this.innerContainer.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleHeaderStuck), 100;
  this.innerContainer.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleSubNavStuck), 200;
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  if (this.timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  }
  this.innerContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleHeaderStuck);
  this.innerContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleSubNavStuck);
}
```

**UPDATE:** All code

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  display:block;
`

class ReviewsPage extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        const tripadvisorLeft = document.createElement("script");
        tripadvisorLeft.src = "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=789&locationId=10467767&lang=en_NZ&rating=true&nreviews=0&writereviewlink=true&popIdx=true&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2";
        tripadvisorLeft.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(tripadvisorLeft);
    }

    render() {           
        return (
            <Wrapper id="tripAdvisor">
                <div id="TA_selfserveprop789" className="TA_selfserveprop">
                    <ul id="3LacWzULQY9" className="TA_links 2JjshLk6wRNW">
                    <li id="odY7zRWG5" className="QzealNl"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default ReviewsPage
```

Comment: Please show your render() method

Comment: Thank you @JasonSpradlin. Have added the code for the component. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, all your `componentDidMount()` is doing is adding a `<script>` tag which references a third party script.  I am assuming that third party script tries to add some information or thing to the DOM (something you can see visually).

However, the DOM only exists between component updates.  React will completely redraw the DOM (the HTML inside your component) any time it detects a change to State or Props.  I'm assuming in this case that Wrapper is what is resetting each time.

I'm not sure how to help with this, mainly because React's entire role in an application is really just managing the state of the DOM, and that script is trying to edit the DOM, but without telling React.  React *might* be sensing an invalid change to the DOM then trying to correct it, but I really don't think React does that. At any rate, the issue is that React is trying to manage the DOM while another thing is trying to edit the DOM, and that's not gonna end well.

It would be better if you could have a script that asynchronously calls to the other service and receives data, then let React apply that data to the DOM, instead of letting the script edit the DOM itself.  Granted, you probably don't have control over how that external script actually works, which is why I say I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, Jason. Now looking at it, the scripts breaks at the point my navigation adds a class. Which got me realising that I had made a typo on the class being added. Now it has been corrected the scripts load fine. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have chosen this answer to my question because Jason was on the mark with "React might be sensing an invalid change to the DOM then trying to correct it, but I really don't think React does that." Anyone having a similar issue should look here first.